# get_terms from registered taxonomies not working

Tags: terms, categories, register-taxonomy

In `functions.php` I can `var_dump()` taxonomies like:

```
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies('','names');
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($taxonomies);
```

which give me:

```
array(7) {
  ["category"]=>
  string(8) "category"
  ["post_tag"]=>
  string(8) "post_tag"
  ["nav_menu"]=>
  string(8) "nav_menu"
  ["link_category"]=>
  string(13) "link_category"
  ["post_format"]=>
  string(11) "post_format"
  ["project"]=>
  string(7) "project"
  ["team"]=>
  string(4) "team"
}
```

Now I would like to get all "categories" from my registered taxonomy "project"

I've tried with get_categories() and get_terms() both returning an empty array.

```
$taxonomies = array(
    'project'
);

$args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'name',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'        => true,
    'exclude'           => array(),
    'exclude_tree'      => array(),
    'include'           => array(),
    'number'            => '',
    'fields'            => 'all',
    'slug'              => '',
    'parent'            => '',
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'child_of'          => 0,
    'get'               => '',
    'name__like'        => '',
    'description__like' => '',
    'pad_counts'        => false,
    'offset'            => '',
    'search'            => '',
    'cache_domain'      => 'core'
);

$terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
var_dump($terms);
```

giving

```
array(0) {
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually have posts in the terms under your custom taxonomy

Comment: ooooooh dammmit @PieterGoosen : Now I have .. and it is working! what do you think, should I delete the question or would you like to write the comment as an answer?

Comment: There is one or two things I want to mention, so I will quickly do a proper answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are just a couple of things I want to point out here using [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

- No need to put one value into an array, you can simply just add the value as is to the variable
- To return your terms, you have to actually have posts assigned to them. By default, empty terms are hidden. The same goes for [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories). If you need to show empty terms as well, just set the `hide_empty` parameter to `false`
- You don't need to call the default values. If you are not going to change the value of a parameter, don't add it to your arguments. Just add those parameters that you are going to change

Here is a proper example

```
$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => false, 
);

$terms = get_terms('project', $args);
var_dump($terms);
```

Here we are getting all the terms, including empty ones, sorted by the default of names from the taxonomy `project`

Comment: Perhaps the best overview of `get_terms()` gotchas that I've seen to date.

Comment: hide_empty which is true by default is what made me lose hours on this. THANKS!